# Terraform empty and non-empty block map variables

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to make backend-service by using Terraform. I use resource_type `google_compute_backend_service`

Now, i have 2 backend-services created by `gcloud` command. The one is using `cdn_policy` [block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_backend_service#cdn_policy) and another one doesn't use `cdn_policy`.

The first backend-services tfstate is like

```
...
"cdn_policy": [
  {
    "cache_key_policy": [],
    "signed_url_cache_max_age_sec": 3600
  }
]
...
```

And the second backend-services is like

```
"cdn_policy": []
```

How to create the terraform script works for both of them ? So, terraform script can run for backend-services who has `cdn_policy` include with its block map and can also run for backend-services without `cdn_policy`.

In my idea, i can create 2 terraform scripts. First for cdn_policy and second without cdn_policy. But, i think this is not best practice.

If i put `cdn_policy = []`, it would result error `An argument named "cdn_policy" is not expected here`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic blocks to create a set of blocks based on a list of objects in an input variable: [Dynamic Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks)

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "service" {

  ...

  dynamic "cdn_policy" {
    for_each = var.cdn_policy

    content {
      cache_key_policy             = cdn_policy.value.cache_key_policy
      signed_url_cache_max_age_sec = cdn_policy.value.signed_url_cache_max_age_sec
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, your answer is good implementation for the first backend-services which it has cdn_policy blocks on tfstate. What about the second backend-services which doesn't have cdn_policy ? The "cdn_policy = []" ?
I give thumbs-up since i didn't know dynamic blocks before, such a good idea.

Comment: if `var.cdn_policy = []` then the dynamic block is not created at all and completely omitted from the resource. it's a create-one-block-per-item-in-the-list. So empty list, no blocks. list with 1 item, 1 block... list with 2 items, 2 blocks, etc.